# Upper limit of get_global_id in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

The openCL `get_global_id` returns an integer. What is the upper bound of the index? Does it depend on the GPU hardware of the system?

Comment: Actually `get_global_id`'s definition is `size_t get_global_id(uint dimindx)`. On a 64 bit system `size_t` is `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not specified limit, apart from the limit that is implied by the return type: `size_t` is an unsigned 32bit value on 32bit systems, and an unsigned 64bit value on 64bit systems ([Khronos Registry about scalar data types](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html))

The global ID is not directly related to the hardware or any of its constraints. It serves as an abstraction of the hardware, and should solely describe the *problem size*. You can define a problem size (that is, a global work size) of 10000, even if your device only has 1000 cores. It is up to the driver/hardware to schedule the execution of the 10000 elements, for example, in 10 chunks of 1000 elements each.

Comment: In fact, it DOES depend on the hardware. On the flag: CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS that is part of the device properties. However I think it does depend more on the driver exposed API.

Comment: @DarkZeros Sure, as I said, it may be 32/64 bits, but when you have a global work size of more than 4294967296, you should consider restructuring your problem anyhow ;-)

Comment: technically, the upper maximum is the product of the size_t values returned when you request CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES with clGetDeviceInfo

Comment: @mfa (Accidentally upvoted the comment, but) the value returned by CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES refer to the **local** work size. E.g. they are 1024/1024/64 on my NVIDIA GPU, which certainly is not the upper limit of the global work size.